# Making a heart pulsate with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have made a heart using CSS. I was just looking for a way to make it beat / pulsate.

Here is the code ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c9yub844/8/)):

```css
#heart {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 90px;
}
#heart:before,
#heart:after {
  position: absolute;    
  -webkit-animation: heart 1s linear infinite;
  content: "";
  left: 50px;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 80px;
  background: red;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
  border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
          transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
#heart:after {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
          transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="heart"></div>
```

Comment: Your heart is broken on Firefox. You forgot `transform-origin: 100% 100%` in `#heart:after`.

Comment: http://lea.verou.me/2012/12/animations-with-one-keyframe/

Comment: @Oriol oops , made it only using -webkit , sorry will update my question

Comment: usage of keyframe could require -webkit-animation, so @Zaqx is in.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/c9yub844/6/ .. on chrome

Comment: Heart with Pulse Animation : https://youtu.be/Jq4diUd10Zs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What a *lovely* post to begin the evening with.

Sure, this is possible with pure CSS - you are likely interested in [animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations):

**CSS**

```
#heart-container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 90px;
    animation: pulsate 0.5s infinite;
}

@keyframes pulsate {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(1.5);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

[Working example on JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/c9yub844/11/)

Just wrap your lovely heart in `#heart-container`, and you are good to go. Also, don't forget to include the vendor specific prefixes where necessary.

FYI, the `animation` shorthand property - similar to `transition` - also accepts an easing setting (timing-function), like `ease-in-out`. Or, use `animation-timing-function`.

See the animation easing [example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c9yub844/9/).

---

**Note**

For anyone wondering why I suggested this approach instead of an alternating animation, this approach synergizes with easing functions pretty well.

Comment: Wow , this looks much better +1 :)

Comment: @MohitBhasi And we are still nowhere near a fancy `cubic-bezier` setting. :)

Comment: There's actually no need for a wrapper. Since the heart is made with `:before` and `:after`, `#heart` is essentially already a wrapper.  Just apply the animation to the `#heart` itself.  http://jsfiddle.net/c9yub844/7/

Comment: I really like the one that is `easing with multiple additional keyframes`, good job!

Answer (score 4):

The `animation` property is your friend. :)

```css
#heart {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 90px;

    -webkit-animation: heartbeat .8s ease-in-out 0s infinite;
    -moz-animation: heartbeat .8s ease-in-out 0s infinite;
    animation: heartbeat .8s ease-in-out 0s infinite;
    transform: scale(1);
}

@-moz-keyframes heartbeat {
    0%   {transform: scale(1);}
    50%  {transform: scale(1.5);}
    100% {transform: scale(1);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes heartbeat {
    0%   {transform: scale(1);}
    50%  {transform: scale(1.5);}
    100% {transform: scale(1);}
}
@keyframes heartbeat {
    0%   {transform: scale(1);}
    50%  {transform: scale(1.5);}
    100% {transform: scale(1);}
}


#heart:before,
#heart:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    left: 50px;
    top: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 80px;
    background: red;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
    border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
            transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
#heart:after {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id = "heart"></div>
```

Comment: One slight simplification, you have `alternate` set on your animation, yet you also handle the alternating within your keyframes.  It's redundant.  You can either get rid of `alternate` or you can simplify your keyframes to only 0% and 100%, the `alternate` will handle going back and forth.

Comment: @MohitBhasi: If you use `ease` instead of `linear` animation, it looks even more like a heartbeat :)

Comment: Is `zoom` standard? Firefox doesn't recognize it. [CSS Device Adaptation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-device-adapt/#the-lsquozoomrsquo-property) defines it, but only to set "the initial zoom factor for the window or viewing area".

Comment: Oh yeah, not working in FF. Updated answer to `transform: scale`, added `ease-in-out` and removed `alternate`

Answer (score 2):

Create a beating heart icon using font-awesome, JQuery and CSS animations.

```
@keyframes heartbeat
    {
      0%
      {
        transform: scale( .75 );
      }
      20%
      {
        transform: scale( 1 );
      }
      40%
      {
        transform: scale( .75 );
      }
       60%
      {
        transform: scale( 1 );
      }
        80%
      {
        transform: scale(.75);
      }
       100%
      {
        transform: scale( 1 );
      }
    }
```

[create beating heart](https://truetocode.com/create-a-beating-heart-icon-using-font-awesome-jquery-and-css-animations/)